How do i change face value of a Zero Coupon Bond in Python rateslib?
I'm currently trying to calculate the effective annual YTM of a Zero Coupon Bond with the following data:

Issue date: 2024/07/01
Maturity date: 2024/09/30
Settlement date (also date of valuation): 2024/07/11
day count basis: 30/360
Market price: 102.010
Face value: 113.1425

With the following code:
from rateslib import FixedRateBond
import datetime as dt

bond = FixedRateBond(
    effective=dt.datetime(2024, 7, 1),
    termination=dt.datetime(2024, 9, 30),
    frequency="A",
    convention="30360",
    fixed_rate=0,
    notional=113.1425
)

bond.ytm(price=102.010, settlement=dt.datetime(2024,7,11), dirty=True)

I get a result of -8.646625824122834, which it should be 60.32 when doing the calculation in Excel. What am i doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

The notional in rateslib is the notional amount owned as a trade, it is not the face value. Face value is just a scaling factor and is not present in rateslib. All bond price calculations are made relative to a face value 100. If you scale your price you will return the result  60.109% from: bond.ytm(price=102.010*100/113.1425, settlement=dt(2024,7,11), dirty=True)
